Mapping through a json array to produce individual <li> in astrojs
I am having problems mapping through a json array to produce individual li's of the array items in astrojs. I was able to successfully map over a card component I made and was able to target specific elements to dynamically pull in json data but I am having trouble with doing the same with the li's. I am able to pull in the json data but it does not showcase as individual li's. All of the data shows up in one li oppose to individual li's. A snippet of my json array and astrojs file code are below.
File: portData.json
"roleList": [ "UX/UI & Strategy", "Art Direction", "Prototyping" ],

File: astrojs code
<ul class="list-none text-base font-light">
   {
     portData.map((portData) => {
       return ( 
         <li>{portData.roleList}</li>
        )
     })
   }


Try portData.roleList.map(role => ....)

James, that seems to not work for me.

@James, This could below seems to work but I do get an error in VS Code that does not stop the output of the code. Please see my code setup below. The error I get is "roles is possibly undefined".
JSON File
"roleList": ["UX/UI & Strategy", "Art Direction", "Prototyping"],
CODE File
the json file that holds the data has been imported and and I setup a variable for the portData.roleList
`const roles = portData.roleList
{
roles.map(roles =>
{roles}
)
}
`

const roles = portData?.roleList and {roles?.map(roles => <li>{roles}</li>)}

@James, wishing you a Merry Christmas, the solution worked.  I looked up the reason for the question mark and it now makes sense. Truly appreciate your help. Blessings.

Yep the ?. is useful for conditional rendering - roles?.map returns null if roles doesn't exist instead of producing an error, and React interprets the null as "render nothing".  Merry Christmas.
